# nested exception is: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.bizm ail.yahoo.com, port: 465

Tags: java, exception

I am not able to connect to smtp port no 465, which uses SSL authentication. Earlier it used to work in default port 25, but have changed the setting to point to 465 for outbound emails for all outgoing emails. This works perfectly fine when I use outlook but shows that it cannot connect to port 465.
Below is the error.

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
nested exception is:
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com, port: 465
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
```

And below is the Javax Mail setting that I use.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", 
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.server.username", "test@yahoo.com");
props.put("mail.server.password", "test123");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter",authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName()); 
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
session.setDebug(sessionDebug);`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want answers, you need to (1) provide the code in question, and (2) provide the *complete* exception with stack trace. Not a link to an image.

Comment: whatever code i wrote is right or not just confirm it as well as if it's right then why it should not connected to the server

Comment: I gave you explicit instructions on how to ask your question, and you've chosen not to follow them. You really can't expect an answer from what you've given.

Comment: i wrote whole details @kdgregory

Comment: OK, now you can get some better answers. For one thing, you can [look at the code that threw this exception](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.mail/mail/1.4.1/javax/mail/Transport.java#218) and learn that you should be calling `getNextException()` to see what the root cause is.

Comment: But first, I would verify that you can actually connect to the host and port. The easiest way to do this is with *telnet*: `telnet smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com 465`. If this times-out, it means that there's something blocking *all* connections to that host and port from your machine, probably a corporate firewall. If that's the case then you need to talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void sendEmail(String emailMessage){

    try{

        final String fromEmail = "*****@yahoo.com";      
        final String password = "*****";                    
        final String toEmail = "*****@yahoo.com";        // can be any email id 
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"); //SMTP Host


        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");                 //TLS Port 465
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");                //enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");     //enable STARTTLS
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");          // enable ssl



        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {


            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));



        message.setSubject("Email From Yahoo JavaMail API");
        message.setText(emailMessage);


        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Email successfully Sent");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

**Try this**

Comment: Do you have any indication whatsoever that this code will solve the OP's problem?

Comment: i did all this things as well as i created separate Authetication class as u mention in above code but still got error

Comment: In yahoo, Go to Account Security options and Turn the “Allow apps that use less secure sign in” setting to “On“. Then it will work.

Comment: i already set “Allow apps that use less secure sign in” still not working